# Jenkins Freestyle Job : Invoke email notification from Evaluated Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, email-ext

I am using a Groovy script to get an email on a list of offline slaves from a Jenkins freestyle job. I have the following code under **Jenkins freestyle Job > Build Environment > Evaluated Groovy script** :

```
import hudson.model.Node
import hudson.model.Slave
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

String[] slaves = []
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.instance

for (Node node in jenkins.nodes) {
  if (!node.toComputer().online) {
    slaves += node.name
    }
}

 println "[OFFLINE SLAVES]: "+slaves

try{
 emailext body: "${slaves}",
    subject: "test subject",
    to: "abc@xyz.com"
}
catch (Throwable t) {
  println(t)
  throw t;
}
```

The slave list is printing out fine but while calling emailext, the following **ERROR** is returned :

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.emailext() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[body:${slaves}, to:abc@xyz.com, subject:test subject]]
> 08:17:48 [EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Problems occurs on injecting env vars defined in the build wrapper: org.jenkinsci.lib.envinject.EnvInjectException: Failed to evaluate the script.

I am new to this and would appreciate some guidance on making this work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
try {
    emailext (
         subject: "test subject",
         to: "abc@xyz.com",
         body: "Offline Slaves : '${slaves}'"
     )
}
```

Comment: Didn't work either. It gave same error - **[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Problems occurs on injecting env vars defined in the build wrapper: org.jenkinsci.lib.envinject.EnvInjectException: Failed to evaluate the script. groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.emailext() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values:[[subject:test subject, to:abc@xyz.com, body:Offline Slaves : [Docker_Enabled,...]]]**

Comment: Try removing the \\ before and after the $slave. I have edited the answer

Comment: Oh ok. Still getting the same error ? I will try it once using your same code.

Comment: Yes, failing with No signature of method: Script1.emailext()

Comment: Could you please try by passing only one value to slaves variable. Don’t pass the array. Just check it once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223621/discussion-between-souravatta-and-s-neenu).

Comment: I had tried passing a text to the body instead of a variable but guess that's not where the issue is.
    emailext (
         subject: "test subject",
         to: "abc@xyz.com",
         body: "Offline Slaves go here'"
     )